# Is there any way to implement a custom lock screen using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, lockscreen, flutter-method-channel

I'm implementing an android app that can change user's lock screen(**not lock screen in app**), for example, an user can change the position of clock in lock screen from top to bottom or else.

Moreover, I want to render some custom widgets, which is implemented using flutter, on the custom lock screen.

I've tried to search relative articles or questions but most of those were about 'implementing an app lock screen'.

Is there any way to implement custom lock screen on flutter? Or do I have to make it with android native code with method channel which can communicate with flutter?

The below image that I've attached is the default lock screen from Samsung Galaxy, and I want to make it a custom lock screen if possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b9Y2.jpg)

Thank you for your answer in advance .

#### Solved

I've implemented it with only 100% Android native code except controlling the custom lock screen's features such as "On/Off LockScreen Feature" and "Clock Position", which is delivered by flutter method channel :D

Answer (score 0):

Some people have created Wall papers apps.

You can check out this package https://pub.dev/packages/async_wallpaper which is the only one maintained if I'm not mistaken.

Also check out this article https://codesearchonline.com/wallpaper-app/

Keep in mind these features are **only available on Android**, so you may as well write them directly in native code

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I'd like to implement "Lock Screen" not wallpaper. For example, if a user pressed "physical hold button on the side of the phone", then default lock screen will be shown. There might be a clock, and other widgets on the lock screen. At this point, I want to make a new custom lock screen to replace the default lock screen. I attached an image link, and it is a custom lock screen of an android app named 'Cash Walk' which is developed by another company in Korea. A user can slide to unlock like iPhone. How can I implement such kind of custom lock screen? Thank you.

Comment: https://koreabyme.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/cash3.jpg